# I got an error on Asp.net(Web-form ). It says Compilation error / Application. The function of click button is not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms, onclick, onclicklistener, buttonclick

**Compilation Error**
**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
**CS1061:** 'signup_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button2_Click' and no accessible extension method 'Button2_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'signup_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Source Error:**

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="text-center">
            <asp:Button ID="Button2"  class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Sign Up" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        </div>
```

.aspx.cs code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                Response.Redirect("home.aspx");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: try to rebuild the solution - if not works try to clean the compiled files

Comment: You showed us the button declaration, but didn't show us the click event handler. Clearly if that's the thing it's complaining about, you need to show it in your question. Please remember we're not at your computer, and there's many things that can go wrong in software development. It's up to you to include adequate details if you want an answer to your question. Please review [mcve].

Comment: I would delete the onclick for the markup of that button, and the in the designer double click on the button to re-create the event. But, you want to look for the existing button code stub in the code behind - looks like it is missing. So try the steps I outline.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the onclick code,i.e cut and paste in .txt file

the re-create the onclick event to the button in the design view ,after which you re-enter the code fron the .txt file into the code window onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the first line of the code.

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/HomeMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm.Login" %>
```

I just change the `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` then it worked fine for me.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/HomeMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebForm.Login" %>
```